# how to insert an image on the home page which can be edited later?

Tags: opencart2.x

I am working with **OpenCart 2.0.1.1**.

I want to **add an image on the homepage** which can be later edited.

So Could anyone give me some step by step guide to create such thing ?

Comment: Why did I get -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below solution for adding image -

1. Go to Extensions > Modules > HTML Content  (If not installed then install it.Click Edit button at the right).
2. Enter Module Name (put any name to recognize it).
3. Click Code View button `</>` in Content area visual editor to switch editor to HTML mode.You can add images here.
4. Make Status as Enabled. Save it.
5. Now Go to System> Design > Layouts and edit Home layout and add above created module to it.

Comment: I have one more question like I can't find the controller of the homepage. I am trying to modify `catalog/controller/common/home.php` (and exiting using exit;) but nothing happens in the homepage. It is still coming.. Could you please suggest me where should I look ?

Comment: Home page controller path - `catalog/controller/common/home.php`. Just go to index function and write `echo "hellow";exit();` 
You will get to see hellow  word on `home` page. If still issue is there try by clearing modification cache.

Comment: I found it in the modification/catalog/controller/common/home.php. It seems someone had made changes using ocmod or vqmod.. for which it resides in the modification folder. Correct me if I am wrong ..

Comment: I want to add some style css for home page only. So can I write the css or javascript in that file itself (i.e. in catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/home.tpl) which is specific to that page only. And of course by using OCMOD ?